# Azure MVC, adding web.config blocks access to website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config

I have an MVC project built in .Net Core 2.2 for Azure.  The project runs locally, but when I upload it to Azure, I receive an error that I do not have permission to read this file or directory, and none of the pages are accessible.  If I remove the web.config file from the project and upload again, it works.  I can also attach an empty web.config and that also works.

**THIS WORKS**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="EditPhrase/BuildPartial">
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="300000" maxQueryStringLength="300000" maxRequestLength="100000" />
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxQueryString="300000" maxUrl="100000" />
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

The path "EditPhrase/BuildPartial" is a POST action in the controller EditPhraseController.